# Cómo lograr colorear un ImageView con Multi-choice en el GridView

Tags: android, gridview, multichoice

Quisiera lograr el efecto de coloreado de la galería de Android, que colorea sobre la imagen seleccionada, así:

[image: Imagen de la gallerya de android material design]

Pero lo que he logrado es sólo colorear los bordes, jugando con la separación y márgenes, ya la imagen se superpone a la coloración por ser coloreada como fondo la imagen tapa el color a pintar. Me quedó asi:

[image: mi galería personalizada]

El ítem del ImageView es éste:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/image_simulator_register"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="120dp"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:contentDescription="Image"
 android:padding="6dp"
 android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_image_default" />
```

El GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_simulator_register_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"/>
```

Utilizo BaseAdapter para llenar mi GridView y el setMultiChoiceModeListener.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo lograr esa selección?

Comment: como lo resolviste?

Answer (score 0):

Trata este método mediante un [selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html), crea un drawable xml dentro de `\drawable`, por ejemplo `miselector.xml`:

defines el color que se mostraría al seleccionar como un color verde, esto dentro de `\values\colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>

</resources>
```

y dentro del layout de tu `GridView`, carga el selector mediante la propiedad `android:listSelector`:

```
<GridView
    ...
    android:listSelector="@drawable/miselector"
   ...
/>
```

Comment: No funciona.
cuando retiro el dedo después de lograr la selección, el color se desaparece como si no estuviera seleccionado.

Comment: El tal caso cuales serian los estados que debo considerar en el selector?

Comment: He probado múltiples combinaciones de estados en el selector y ninguna me funciona.

Comment: ¿Alguien sabe si puede lograr usando un selector?